# Is bitwise operation the right one to solve the following?

Tags: mysql, database-design, bitwise-or

I am into create an application for a marble manufacture company 
to keep track of the marble generation process with given width and 
height. This keeps track of

Here is the table schema of how i am going to organise my data. 
The first one is `StoneInfo` which contains basic information about
 a stone like “unique_id, stone_id, stone_name, creation_time, last_purchase_time, 
generation_status”

unique_id - is a random generated id - this is to maintain a foreign key relationship with the other table `StoneMetaDetails`

**StoneInfo**

```
UNIQUE ID        (Primary key)
STONE ID         (Indexed & Unique key)
STONE_NAME       (Indexed & Unique key)
CREATION_TIME  
LAST_PURCHASE_TIME
GENERATION_STATUS
```

To avoid the second normalisation anomaly i have splitted into two tables. Here it contains details about the creation status of each type of stone in a specified dimension. The creation status  is something like

```
CREATED_SUCCESSFULLY
CREATION_INPROGRESS
CRAETION_ON_HOLD_DUE_TO_LESS_REQUIREMENT
CREATION_ON_HOLD_DUE_TO_LACK_OF_RESOURCE
CREATION_ON_HOLD_DUE_TO_LACK_OF_MACHINE
CREATION_ON_HOLD
```

**StoneMetaDetails**

```
UNIQUE ID          (FOREIGN KEY with on delete cascade)
FORMAT             (PRIMARY KEY)
DIMENSION          (PRIMARY KEY)
CREATION_STATUS
STORE_NAME
WEIGHT
QUANTITY_AVAILABLE
MACHINE TYPE/MACHINE ID
```

I want to maintain the creation status of each and every type of stone (which might have different flavours and dimension in them). All i want is to minimise the read/write operations on the table for quicker access.

I am maintaining two status values like `GENERATION_STATUS` and 
`CREATION_STATUS` because

`GENERATION_STATUS` - when it is is ("generated" or "on hold for some reasons" or "the generation process have started/initialized")
`CREATION_STATUS` - is maintained to keep track of the exact status value for specific stone type with its dimension.

Here I am trying to merge both these column values with `GENERATION_STATUS` column value with the help of bitwise or operation - by assigning different constant values (in 2^ relation)

```
//All these values are meant for stone type

public static final long STONE_TYPE_MARBLE_20_X_30 = 2;
public static final long STONE_TYPE_MARBLE_50_X_60 = 4;
public static final long STONE_TYPE_MARBLE_10_X_60 = 8;
public static final long STONE_TYPE_MARBLE_20_X_60 = 16;
public static final long STONE_TYPE_MARBLE_40_X_60 = 32;
public static final long STONE_TYPE_MARBLE_60_X_60 = 64;


public static final long STONE_TYPE_LIMESTONE_10_X_30 = 128;
public static final long STONE_TYPE_LIMESTONE_10_X_40 = 256;

public static final long STONE_TYPE_TRAVERTINE = 512;
public static final long STONE_TYPE_MARBLE = 1024;
public static final long STONE_TYPE_GRANITE = 2048; (2^11)

//Have alloted values for 2^0 to 2^14 for stone type 
//All these variables are meant for representing creation/generation status of a stone 
public static final long GENERATION_SUCCESS = 2^15;
public static final long GENERATION_IN_PROGRESS = 2^16;
public static final long GENERATION_ON_HOLD_DUE_TO_MINIMAL_REQUIREMENT = 2^17;
public static final long GENERATION_ON_HOLD_DUE_TO_LACK_OF_MACHINE = 2^18;


public static final long GENERATION_ON_HOLD_DUE_TO_MACHINE_COULD_NOT_GENERATE = 2^19;

//Some ten to fifteen different types of generation error values may be possible
```

So that i could obtain it without joining the other table for faster access.

To be more clear i am trying to map,

`stone_id` and its `generation_status` in `StoneInfo` table. So that `generation_status` contains the status value irrespective of the stone type and its dimensions.

ie; (STONE_A_10_X_20 | GENERATION_SUCCESS) | (STONE_A_20_X_30 | GENERATION_INPROGRESS) in a single column.

Is this possible with the help of bitwise OR? Am i going in the right way? Or please suggest me an alternative to handle this in a much better way.

Thanks for being patient to read this long problem story :)

Comment: I tried to explain my problem... Please comment here if i have to add further details or edit the post with additional information which is required... to get a better clarity on the question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MySQL, there are two relevant datatypes:

- `ENUM` -- stored as a 1- or 2-byte integer, and represents 1 of N values.  (N is limited to 64K values -- but even a few hundred is unwieldly.)
- `SET` -- stored as a larger integer, and contains (internally) any combination of 1-bit values (1, 2, 4, 8, etc, a la what you described in code).  (Set is limited to 64 bits, a la `BIGINT`.)
- Both `ENUM` and `SET` use arbitrary strings (not numbers) for representing the values.

The `|` operator "ors" together two bit strings.  This works fine for `SET`, but does not make as much sense for one bit of a `SET`.

`generation_status` makes sense as an `ENUM`, not a set -- after all, the status can take on only one value at a time, correct?  So, a boolean expression involving `GENERATION_SUCCESS` needs to say `(generation_status = "GENERATION_SUCCESS")`, which resolves to TRUE or FALSE, which is represented as 1 or 0, which can be used in Boolean `|` or Logical `OR`.

An unrelated issue... It rarely makes sense to have 3 unique keys on a table, as you seem to have on StoneInfo.

Answer (score 1):

Simple Answer is **you are going in the right direction**.

As I understand you already know the logic behind this operation and so to confirm that this is the right way to go and store multiple statuses in single field we may have to look at other things and difference may be negligible when implementing this.

See [this link](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3359321/Storing-Multiple-Statuses-Using-an-Integer-Column.htm) for more basic explanation and I would suggest go with it and put some test data into your db then run some queries to compare results.
You may see that keeping them in two columns and doing an OR between them and keeping both columns to reduced number of bits might be quicker. I have not checked this but [theoratically](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/91642/performance-of-bitwise-operators-on-byte-column-vs-individual-bit-columns) (DBAs are expensive and storage is cheap) it would be good to have Stone Type status and Generation status in a separate column taking just 8 bits to cover for combination of 256 statuses etc.

Try it.

Comment: I would like to club these two different values in order to avoid joining - presuming that join is a costly operation. Am I right with this perception?

Comment: I can say you are correct for most cases. However try it on your data and profile performance and storage to optimise it for your needs.